# Convert an Angularjs Protractor promise from a string to float?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, karma-runner, protractor

I'm using Angular.js Protractor to get check the values of cells in a grid.  I'm able to get the values, but they are strings, and I'd like to do calculations with them.

When I try this:

```
ptor.findElements(protractor.By.className('ngCellText')).then(function(cells) {
  expect(parseFloat(cells[16].getText())).toEqual(parseFloat(cells[14].getText()) / parseFloat(cells[11].getText()));
});
```

I get the error: `Expected NaN to equal NaN.`

I read that promises are asynchronous, and you can't convert them with a synchronous function, so I tried this:

```
element.all(by.className('ngCellText')).then(function(text1) {
  element.all(by.className('ngCellText')).then(function (text2) {
    element.all(by.className('ngCellText')).then(function (text3) {
      expect(parseFloat(text1[16].getText())).toEqual(parseFloat(text2[14].getText()) + parseFloat(text3[11].getText()));
    });
  });
});
```

And I get the same error: `Expected NaN to equal NaN.`

If anyone could help me out, that'd be great!

Comment: in your first example, try console logging the cell text to make sure you have the correct cell that you want, i.e.: 

`console.log(cells[16].getText())`

In addition, I use a slightly different syntax to get my elements by  id, for example:

`ptor.findElements(by.className('ngCellText')).then(function (cells) {})`

Comment: I printed the cell, and it seems to be right. I get the string '1.40', and I'd like to treat it like a number.

Comment: I tried using the ptor. syntax as well. I'm able to get the strings fine, but when I use parseFloat() on them, they turn into NaN.

Comment: Hmm, strange.  Not sure what to do if you have the right string, and parseFloat() just isn't parsing correctly.  I'd just try separating everything as much as possible.  `var cell=cell[16]; var cellVal=cell.getText(); var cellFloat = parseFloat(cellVal);`

Not sure.

Comment: Still no luck, thanks for the suggestions though. This is very strange. cellFloat is '1.40'. If I do parseFloat(cellFloat), it turns into NaN. If I do parseFloat('1.40'), it turns into 1.40.

Actually, cellVal is only '1.40' when I run it through the expect statement. When I console.log it, it prints 
`code
{ then: [Function: then],
  cancel: [Function: cancel],
  isPending: [Function: isPending] }`

Comment: Ah, that's because the expect statement waits for the promise to resolve before expecting. 

The output you're seeing, with `then`, `cancel`, and `isPending` is a promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, now that we know that `getText()` returns a promise:

```
cells[16].getText().then(function (cellValue) {
    console.log(cellValue); // This should give you '1.40'

    var floatVal = parseFloat(cellValue);
    console.log(floatVal); // This should give you 1.4

    expect(floatVal).toBe(1.4);
});
```

Comment: No problem! I just figured out a few things like this last night and this morning, so it feels good to show someone else (I know the protractor docs are pretty sparse and hard to find good information)

Answer (score 0):

You can also assign it to a variable using the arrow function:

```
var someVal = $(elem).getText().then(value => +value);
```

Or use parseFloat() if you need specific int.